# Nuxt 3 useAsyncData access previous value with refresh method

Tags: server-side-rendering, infinite-scroll, nuxt3, asyncdata

I am trying to implement infinite scroll using nuxt3.

**Key target:**
Initial load should contain server rendered content

So my code is

```
const { data, refresh } = await useAsyncData(async () => {
  const response = await $fetch(`/api/whatever?limit=${limit}&skip=${skip}`);

  return {
    totalElements: response.count,
    items: response.items,
  };
});
```

Everything is fine here except I couldn't accumulate previous result with current result after `refresh()` to achieve infinite scroll because `data` is not accessible inside `useAsyncData` handler so i can't use

```
return {
  totalElements: response.count,
  items: [...data.value.items, ...response.items],
};
```

Also it is impossible to assign current value to `ref` and reuse it inside handler as server `ref` will take changes and client `ref` will be empty value at initial load.

I have a workaround but it is a kind of a crutch and sometimes results to a glitchy scroll behaviour because server rendered `data.value.items` is an array of objects and after modifying `data.value.items` on client side it becomes an array of proxies.

```
  // This code is outside useAsyncData composable
  ...
  const response = await useFetch(...);
  data.value.items = [...data.value.items, ...response.items];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I don't know if this is the right way to do it but it works! Seems like `data` is accessible inside `useAsyncData` on client side so I just have to check it first.

```
const { data, refresh } = await useAsyncData(async () => {
  const response = await $fetch(
    `/api/whatever?limit=${limit}&skip=${skip}`,
  );

  if (response) {
    return {
      totalElements: response.count,
      items: data?.value?.items
        ? [...data.value.items, ...response.items]
        : response.items,
    };
  }
});
```

And in scrollHandler I can use `refresh` now. Hope it can help anyone who's struggling with infinite scroll and nuxt3.

Comment: Nice solution, although requires some additional TS typing and having watch instead of refresh would also help.

Answer (score 0):

The callback in the `useAsyncData` hook uses the Nuxtapp instance as a parameter (`app`). Through this parameter, you can access the current value of your `useAsyncData` by the set key.

```js
const { data } = useAsyncData('my-data', async (app) => {
    // reference the previous data
    const previousData : Result | undefined = app?._asyncData?.['my-data']?.data.value;

    console.log(previousData);

    // Fetch the new data
    const result : Result = await $fetch('/api/whatever');

    return result
});
```